# Backup updates on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, updates

I am planning on formatting my laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium that has gathered up a lot of unwanted programs etc.. and re-installing Windows. The problem is that internet is very expensive in Sri Lanka and I would like to backup all the updates installed and restore them. I don't have WSUS repositories.

Is there any way to do this? I appreciate any help ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is highly unlikely.

I found this Microsoft support question:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b65af122-f4db-4053-a22d-f2b1081cc01e/windows-update-temporary-folder-location

**Statement**

> Windows Update (and for all I know other MS Update services) appears todownload to a temporary folder in the root of the drive with the most free space at the time of the download.

**Answer**

> This is not an accurate statement. The Windows Update Agent downloads ALL content to %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download. If you're downloading from the Microsoft Download Center, IE may be writing the temporary file into the cache before copying to the final destination. **Windows Installer does create a temporary folder** on the logical volume with the most free space, during the actual installation process, **but that folder is be deleted after use.**

Even if you could backup your windows updates individually, how will you know which order to install them in. Your best bet is going to be to create a full backup of your OS in a clean state.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any easy way to backup the updates but if you chose to re-install then you can make a backup of you clean updated windows after you have updated it, so next time you have to restore you will only have to download updates that are newer than the updates you had when you made the backup.

A guide of how to do that can be found here: [backup-and-restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to see whether there are any other answers. Anyway, I will hearafter not update via the built-in update system in Windows but via WSUS so that I can have backup copies.